# formatting rows in a single file

Tags: awk, sed

I am bit new to unix shell , i have a file like below

cat dbschema

```
                  TABLE_NAME                  | TABLE_SIZE_BEFORE_RANDOM_MB
----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------
 SEC_CDS_SS |                    0.125000

                  TABLE_NAME                  | TABLE_SIZE_AFTER_RANDOM_MB
----------------------------------------------+----------------------------
 SEC_CDS_SS |                   0.125000

 TABLE_NAME  | TABLE_SIZE_BEFORE_RANDOM_MB
-------------+-----------------------------
 CDS_EV|                   28.625000

 TABLE_NAME  | TABLE_SIZE_AFTER_RANDOM_MB
-------------+----------------------------
 CDS_EV |                   0.500000
```

I need output like below in the same file like

cat dbschema

```
 TABLE_NAME                  | TABLE_SIZE_BEFORE_RANDOM_MB            TABLE_SIZE_AFTER_RANDOM_MB
----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------
 SEC_CDS_SS                     0.125000                               0.125000
 CDS_EV                          28.625000                              0.500000
```

Pipe as to be removed in the outfile as well,

I tried matching the first column

```
awk '$1!=p{if(p)print s; p=$1; s=$0; next}{sub(p,x); s=s $0} END{print s}' dbschema
```

also tried some sed to concat 2 rows of a column

```
awk 'ORS=(NR%2==0) ?"\n" :" "' dbschema
```

none seems get me correct answer , any help much appreciated .. please

also is their a way to ignore a echo line when running a sh file ??

I have some line in my sh as

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< TEST >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> (in sh files , this line should be ignored and proceed with further lines in that sh file )
```

Many thanks

Comment: Many thanks guys for helping in format ,i will make sure to format in next question ..

Comment: Any solution for the above question is really much appreciated , thanks

Comment: What does the line under `I have some line in my sh as` have to do with your `dbschema` input file? If it's something that could be present in your input then include it in your sample input, don't add it as an afterthought elsewhere in your question. And please check that the sample input and expected output in your question is **exactly** correct, including layout, characters, and values - it looks suspiciously haphazard to me.

Comment: Hi Ed, It is just a while loop and it has nothing to do with the primary question .

Comment: and yes the input and the output is wat expected except the pipe should not be their in the expected output , thanks

Comment: "except the pipe should not be their in the expected output" But you want the `--+---` to remain? I would skip parsing the headers altogether and use a `printf "HEADER STUFF\n"` as needed. Then your logic can focus on capturing the right value for the right position. Also, are you sure the generating system can't produce all data for each TABLE_NAME on one line (altogehter)? Most database clients have a `-w` (width) that you can set to 10000 or whatever, so there is no  unneeded wrapping of data (not exactly what you show here). That would simplify your problem significantly. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Shelter even --+---  can also go not needed , thought it will look nice dosent matter . Actually what i am doing is getting the table size before i change the table DDL and taking the table size after the  DDL change , so cant be taken from sytem in one time . Doing some processing between 2 commands , thanks

Answer (score 1):

This satisfies your requirements:

```sh
awk -F '|' 'BEGIN {header = 1;}
$2 ~ /BEFORE_RANDOM/ {before = 1; if (header) {printf("%s",$0);}}
$2 ~ /AFTER_RANDOM/ {if (header) {printf(" | %s\n",$2); header = 0;}}
/^-/ || /^ *$/ {next;}
$1 !~ /TABLE_NAME/ {
    table = $1;
    if (before) {size_before = $2; before = 0;}
    else {printf("%-30s %12.6f %12.6f\n",table,size_before,$2);}
}' dbschema
```

- Prints header info once.
- Doesn't print the `-----+-----` line
- Skips blank lines and lines that start with dashes.
- Prints one row per table, no pipe delimiters

Edited version for "before" and "after" data in separate files:

Save this as `table-size-changes` and `chmod +x table-size-changes`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS = "|";}

/^-/ || /^ *$/ {next;}

{gsub(/ /,"");}

# First file has the "before" info
FNR == NR && !len[2] && /TABLE_NAME/ {
    len[2] = length($2);
    hdr[1] = $1;
    hdr[2] = $2;
}

FNR == NR && /TABLE_NAME/ {next;}

FNR == NR {
    tbl[$1] = $2;
    if (length($1) > len[1]) {len[1] = length($1);}
}

# Second file has the "after" info
FNR < NR && !len[3] && /TABLE_NAME/ {
    len[3] = length($2);
    hdr[3] = $2;

    # print output header
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        printf("%s%" len[i] "s", pad, hdr[i]);
        pad = " | ";
    }
    printf("\n");
}

FNR < NR && /TABLE_NAME/ {next;}

FNR < NR {
    pad = "";
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        val[1] = $1; val[2] = tbl[$1]; val[3] = $2;
        printf("%s%" len[i] "s", pad, val[i]);
        pad = "   ";
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

If the data from your original question is split into two files, and you run the above script, you get the following output:

```sh
table-size-changes before.txt after.txt
```

```
TABLE_NAME | TABLE_SIZE_BEFORE_RANDOM_MB | TABLE_SIZE_AFTER_RANDOM_MB
SEC_CDS_SS                      0.125000                     0.125000
    CDS_EV                     28.625000                     0.500000
```

Comment: Many thanks Bill, i will try this out , many thanks

Comment: Hi bill , sorry for asking more , is that possinble do the same from 2 files .I am

Comment: TABLE_NAME  | TABLE_SIZE_BEFORE_RANDOM_MB is coming from one file and TABLE_NAME  | TABLE_SIZE_AFTER_RANDOM_MB coming from another file , just match the table and get details like above in some output file ?? Possible Bill ?? Thanks

Comment: It works unbelievable Bill , take a Bow from me Bill , Many Many thanks much appreciated .